# Trying to center a breakout div at bottom of page

Tags: css, html, center, using

I'm trying to center a breakout div at the bottom of my page using the following CSS:

```
#footer {
clear: both;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

I've bee working on this for hours and what's really frustrating is that I got it to work earlier but broke some other things with my other two divs and made some changes that fixed the problem but since then I've been completely unable to center the footer. It just doesn't look right aligned to the left or right.

I've tried suggestions from other web sites such as setting the left and right margin to 100% and margin: 0 auto; among other things. Nothing is working and my head is spinning.

How should I approach this seemingly easy problem?

Here is my footer, in case it helps:

```
<footer id="footer">
<address>webmaster@mydomain.net</address>
</footer>
```

I also tried using align-text: center both inline and in the external stylesheet that I'm using. Before I was able to get it working using that CSS in the external stylesheet. Then I make a bunch of changes really fast without keeping a record of what I was doing.

Please help?

Comment: remove position absolute and try margin:0 auto;

Comment: No, that didn't work and I forgot to add: I'm trying to position the footer to be always at the bottom of the screen and removing position absolute puts it at the stop of the screen.

Comment: please first give width to footer than add margin:auto;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you define `position:absolute;left: 0;` then `margin:0 auto;` will not work obviously..

i think following trick will work for you...

```
#footer {
  clear:both;
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:50%;
  margin-left: -100px;

}
```

As you are using `position: absolute;` you cant use `margin:0 auto;`..in such cases  `left:50%;margin-left: -100px;` is used generally to center a div horizontally

example:: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CTPzZ/)**

Comment: That worked even better, it "automatically" positioned it. Maybe I'm just being OCD about this, but I know that I did it differently earlier and I would like to know how I did it for future reference. I'm totally ok with this solution though. It really helped me. Thank you.

Comment: ) .... generally to make a div horizontally center you can use `margin:0 auto;` but for this you will need to declare a `width:xxx px` and no `postion:absolute` ........ if you use `postion:absolute;` then you may use the above trick to center a div

Answer (score 0):

if you want to center div with position absolute than try this

```
#footer {
clear: both;
width:80%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 50%;
margin-left:-40%; /*should be half of footer width and it should be in -margin*/
}
```

Comment: That works, in that I can move the text to the left or right by changing the values and I have it just about perfect. There's no way a user could tell. This is a dumb question but how do you get the length of the footer (it has 27 characters) and what is -margin*/? Thanks.

Comment: im happy its worked for you please next time if you give a proper example it will be lot easier